# Is there a quick way to move a bunch of static constants to another (non-nested) class?

Tags: java, eclipse

I started using static constants in my main class, but now the number is very large and I would like to refactor them into their own config file/class (say, Constants.java). However, all references must now access these constants by first applying the Constants.*-prefix. Instead of doing a manual search and replace for each constant, is there a way to do it quickly for all constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has a feature in the `Refactor...` menu called `Move...` that does this for you. Right click the field you want to move, select the option, and type the name of the type to move the field to. This will add/remove any required `import` statements.

Comment: This might also take a long time if there are a lot of constants.

Comment: I only see packages after highlighting a constant and then clicking move. I need to target the actual class Constants.java. I'm using the default package.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn In the input box that opens up, just write  the fully qualified name of the type to which you want to move the constant.

Comment: Ok now that I just highlighted the variable without the modifiers I see the input box. However, after moving, the class prefix is not applied to references to the constant.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn Those won't be necessary if an appropriate `import` statement is generated.

Comment: Actually, it just applied the prefix this time. Idk why it didnt do it before. Thank you. Although I should say that Charlie's concern is correct, it only works for one constant at a time.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn Consider looking into other IDEs. Maybe Intellij does a better job at this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Pragmatically, I think he is better off just doing it the hard way.  The amount of effort in researching other IDEs, picking one, installing it, configuring it, loading his code ... and then trying to figure out how to do this refactoring ... is more than he is saving.

Comment: @StephenC Yeah, I would too. (But for the long term...)

Answer (score 1):

One could place the constants in an interface, and let the class implement that interface.

*In general defining constants elsewhere can be problematic: they might be stored in the using class' constant pool, and hence no longer have an import to the originating class. Then some compilers/class loaders won't detect after a change to the constants java that a recompile of the using source is necessary. That sounds dumb, but was the case in the past.*